# Insert_id no inserta el id correcto, inserta un 1

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un tpl en donde los datos adicionales del usuario aparecen, el problema que tengo es que cuando el usuario actualiza sus datos yo uso un insert_id para insertar los datos de la patologia y por alguna razon, éste insert_id pone la id como 1 cuando eso no es cierto

Aquí esta el codigo en si que causa el problema

```
$sql11 = "
            INSERT INTO `ec_patologia`(`id_estatus`, `descripcion_patalogia`) 
            VALUES ('1','".$Fisico."')";
            array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql11));
            $pato_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

            $hoy = date("Y/m/d");

            $sql12 = "
            SELECT * FROM `ec_patologia_usuario` WHERE `id_usuario` = '$Id_usuario';";
            array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql12));

            $result = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql12);// or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

            if(!$result){
                $sql13 = "
                INSERT INTO `ec_patologia_usuario`(`id_patologiausuario`, 
                `id_usuario`, `id_patologia`, `id_estatus`, 
                `fecha_patologia`, `operation`, `date_upd`) 
                VALUES ('','$Id_usuario','$pato_id','1','$hoy','INSERT','$hoy');";
                array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql13));

            }else{
                $sql13 = "
                UPDATE `ec_patologia_usuario` SET `id_patologia` = '$pato_id' 
                AND `date_upd` = '$hoy'
                WHERE `id_usuario` = '$Id_usuario';";
                array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql13));
            }
```

Esta es la estructura de la tabla ec_patologia_usuario

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_patologia_usuario` (
  `id_patologiausuario` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_patologia` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_estatus` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_patologia` date NOT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'nombre de la operacion realizada en esa fila',
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'ultima modificacion',
  `create_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_USER()' COMMENT 'usuario que creo la operacion'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `ec_patologia_usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_patologiausuario`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `ec_patologia_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `ec_patologia_usuario`
  MODIFY `id_patologiausuario` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=22;
COMMIT;
```

Esta es la estructura de la tabla ec_patologia

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_patologia` (
  `id_patologia` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_estatus` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion_patalogia` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `ec_patologia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_patologia`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `ec_patologia`
--
ALTER TABLE `ec_patologia`
  MODIFY `id_patologia` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=42;
COMMIT;
```

EDICION:

Edite el sql para que inserte ec_patologia asi, y ahora retorna 0 insert_id

```
    $sql11 = "
    INSERT INTO `ec_patologia`(`id_patologia`, `id_estatus`, `descripcion_patalogia`) 
    VALUES ('', '1','".$Fisico."')";
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql11));
    $pato_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Comment: Muéstranos el resultado actual de un `SHOW CREATE TABLE ec_patologia;`  si el problema es en esa tabla (lo cual no queda claro en la pregunta). Y si es en `ec_patologia_usuario` muéstranos qué arroja un `SHOW CREATE TABLE ec_patologia_usuario;`

Comment: Es un ec_patologia_usuario. Inserta un 1 en donde debe estar "id_patologia"

Comment: Podria ser el problema que $sql11 = "
            INSERT INTO `ec_patologia`(`id_estatus`, `descripcion_patalogia`) 
            VALUES ('1','".$Fisico."')";
Le estas asignando el valor 1 y no $pato_id una vez asignado el valor

Comment: lo primero que noto a simple vista es `SELECT * FROM ec_patologia_usuario WHERE "id_usuario" = '$Id_usuario';";` cuando en realidad deberia quedar  `SELECT * FROM ec_patologia_usuario WHERE "id_usuario" = '$Id_usuario'";`

Comment: Es que estatus 1 significa activo, voy a probar insertando el id vacio

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más claro en la pregunta? Ya hemos avanzado, sabemos que el problema es en la tabla `ec_patologia_usuario` (debiste haberlo dicho al principio). Ahora, pregunto, ¿en qué columna te está insertando el valor `1`? ¿qué valor debería insertar? ¿qué depuraciones has hecho de las variables que estás usando?

Comment: Me la inserta en 'id_patologia', ese id_patologia viene de insert_id que se genera cuando se inserta una patologia nueva en ec_patologia

Comment: No funciono mi idea, mostro un 0 en ec_patologia_usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decídi reprogramar todo como ven aqui, cambie el update y el if

```
    $sql11 = "
    INSERT INTO `ec_patologia`(`id_patologia`, `id_estatus`, `descripcion_patalogia`) 
    VALUES ('', '1','".$Fisico."')";
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql11));
    $pato_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $hoy = date("Y/m/d");
    $sql12 = "
    SELECT * FROM `ec_patologia_usuario` WHERE `id_usuario` = $Id_usuario;";

    $result2 = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql12);// or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result2); 
    
    if($rowcount > 0){
        $sql13 = "UPDATE `ec_patologia_usuario` SET `id_patologia` = '$pato_id', `operation` = 'UPDATE' 
        WHERE `id_usuario` = '$Id_usuario';";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql13);

    }else{
        $sql13 = "
        INSERT INTO `ec_patologia_usuario`(`id_patologiausuario`, 
        `id_usuario`, `id_patologia`, `id_estatus`, 
        `fecha_patologia`, `operation`, `date_upd`) 
        VALUES ('','$Id_usuario','$pato_id','1','$hoy','INSERT','$hoy');";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql13);
    }

if($result == true){

    return $result;

}else{

    return null;

}
```